# MySQL crashes daily on VPS with Ubuntu Server 12.04 - How can I find the error or conflict?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Every day for the past four days, my website server crashes at least once. (Error establishing database connection.

As long as I catch it, I simply have to do the following command:

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

and its up and running in about 30 seconds.

I imagine this is not enough info to diagnose, but I am sure there is an error log or something I can pull which would be more useful.

It is running on a single core w/ 512 mb memory. The whole site is funneled through CloudFlare, so even at peak traffic it never really sees an average load above `0.25` when checking `htop`.

One random thought - I have an embedded twitter feed that shows latest tweets. It happened today immediately after the tweet was posted. I have no idea if there is a connection and didn't pay attention the last few days when tweeting. Just thought I would throw it out there in case someone knows of a conflict.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Check you **my.log** !  ,it sits in **/var/log/my.log** !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the value of the variable "log_error":

```
select @@log_error
```

or

```
show variables like 'log_error'
```

It defaults to /var/log/mysqld.log on a RHEL6 server though can be different.

Then check this log file - it will generally give you a reason why it's failing.

Alternatively, if the service is being killed because the server is running out of memory, check the system log:

```
/var/log/messages
```

For the "Out Of Memory killer" doing it's thing or any other messages that might be relevant around the time that the server died.

Comment: Looks like it was out of memory. Thank you. Apparently I can't upvote or mark this as correct because of my account newbie status.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Off topic question for you. I have been using my google id to log in, and whenever I use a different stack service (like dba or stackoverflow) my reputation starts at zero. Is it supposed to transfer across platforms, or are you just considered a noob again in any new section?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.  I'm relatively new too :)